# Need help with a set-associative cache memory problem

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache

I'm studying for my Computer Architecture exam next week, and I'm having problems understanding how a set associative cache works and how to solve related problems like this one :

"A set-associative cache memory uses a set of 8 words. A replacement procedure based on FIFO algorithm is implemented by means of 3-bit counter associated with each word in the set. A value in the range 0-7 is thus recorded for each word. When a hit occurs, the counter associated with the referenced word is set to 1; those with values originally lower than the referenced one are put in its place and put all others in reverse order. If a miss occurs the algorithm implemented the new word put in its place, show that this procedure works with this message "start ABCDEFGHIJKABCDEFLMNGHD end". Start with initial 8 words. then compute the miss ratio."

**here is what I've tried so far ... I've inserted the first 8 letters into the cache, and then checked the following 15 letters for hits and misses whenever there is a miss I remove the oldest letter in the cache and replace it with the new one... not sure if my solution is correct to this point or not and I can't figure out the part about the counter and the part about the reverse order**

I greatly appreciate any time taken to explain this to me as I don't understand the wording of the problem, and need a general guideline on how to solve such problem.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We want to help you with your specific problems, not just solve your exercise for you. However, as it is we don't know what this problem is and thus how to help. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or concrete steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See also [our homework policy](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/470/), [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594), and our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: Dear D.W. this is not a homework or an assignment, this is a question from a test in the last semester which I'm using as in example to learn how to solve problems related to this subject. I understand the basic idea of set-associative caching but I can't seem to figure out how to solve related problems. All I want is an explanation of the subject and a general guideline (hints) to solve related problems.

Comment: Please re-read my comment; I already understood all that when I wrote it.  The issue is not whether it is a homework or an assignment; the issue is that it is a dump of a problem statement, which our policies consider unsuitable for this site.  We expect you to make a serious effort on your own, show us what you have tried, and where you got stuck, tell us what you do and don't understand, and find a way to craft a specific technical question about something specific that you don't understand.  Bottom line: re-read my comment and the links there; they apply to your question.

Comment: When you say you don't understand the wording of the question, which part don't you understand? A general explanation of set-associative caches is beyond the scope of this site but it should be in your text book, in books in your library and on Wikipedia.

Comment: I apologize, this is my first time posting a question here ... I wrote down what I've tried so far and the parts I couldn't solve. hope this is good enough.

Comment: @user18013 And you have quickly learned that people aren't going to help you here (despite the fact that this is a perfectly good question)...I'm trying to understand your question, but I fear I won't be able to answer in time.  BTW, the people giving you guff probably don't know the answer because (imo) the question is odd so instead of saying they don't know they simply recognize this question as a qualifying exam question and refuse to answer.  This is very typical of this site.

Comment: Without a definition of word size (32-bit? 16-bit?) relative to character size (8-bit utf-8? 16-bit utf-16?) the question is unanswerable. It is only *implied* that there is only 1 set. The explanation of the replacement policy is *very* unclear. (I would *guess* that a hit is supposed to set the counter to 0 not 1 [unless a line fill sets the counter to 0] and that the victim is the line with the highest number. It also *seems* the lower counter values are replaced with the counter value for the hit line, but this could result in 7 lines having highest counter with no way to choose a victim.)

Comment: I am tempted to speculate that the question is attempting to describe a clumsy implementation of LRU replacement (that the counter is an access ordering), but the description is not consistent with LRU (or MRU). If this was a problem you were actually required to solve, I would suggest describing your interpretation of how the replacement policy actually works and then solving the problem.

Comment: @Jared thank you for pointing that out. I've also felt that my question isn't just to get an answer. It's more of a "Learn By Example", just wanted someone to help solve this so I can understand the basic "algorithm" for such problems. Thank you again for your comment :)

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton ... I completely agree with you about the replacement policy being unclear, I've failed to understand it along with the function of the counter. and yes she does give problems like this one to solve in the exam, she is known for her "unclear" questions. I'll try to solve it again from the start and upload it here if I come up with better results. Thank you very much sir for your effort, if you think of anything else please let me know

Comment: As @PaulA.Clayton pointed out, it's hard to answer.  First, what is the size of the cache?  It sounds like it's actually a fully associative cache (i.e. a set-associative cache with a single set) and thus the size of the cache is 8 "letters".  Second, a cache works on **memory addresses** _not_ **values**!  So that part doesn't make sense.  I have no idea what this means: _"those with values originally lower than the referenced one are put in its place and put all others in reverse order."_  How can you put more than one value into the cache hit's place?

Comment: @Jared I am fairly certain that the "values" are the metadata used for replacement. I was *guessing* that "put in its place" meant 'put in/take the value of the hit line's replacement position/order number'. This could mean that the line with the next lower numbered line received the hit line's number and each and the next lower number line one less than that etc. This *might* be what was meant by "all others [lines with originally lower numbers] in reverse order". This would implement LRU (if 7 is victim), but why not just say LRU?!

Comment: @Jared yes, it doesn't really feel like a set-associative as it doesn't require the use of it's main feature ... the part about the replacement policy is the confusing part like you just said.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton so are you saying that it is solvable as LRU ??

Comment: @user18013 I was just guessing at what was meant. *If* a hit (or replacement) makes the hit (or replaced) line's metadata value 0, the lines with lower values are increased by one (so the next to lowest gets the old value of the hit line), and the line with 7 is the victim, then this is LRU. Whether that is what was meant in the question seems dubious, but other interpretations don't make much sense either (e.g., setting the hit to 1, all lower values to the old hit value, and reversing the order of the higher values; victim is highest value with random selection among duplicates).

Comment: If I were answering such on an exam, I would explain what I thought was meant (including assuming a typo/thought-o for "referenced word is set to 1", size(character)=size(word), one set, etc.), and my explanation of LRU seems to make the most sense (to me). However, assuming a typo is probably not a good idea as a grader is even less likely to give partial credit when changing stated (not just implicit) properties. A reasonable grader would give at least partial credit to an answer consistent with "reasonable" assumptions, but reasonable grading seems unlikely given *unreasonable* questions.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton I believe this is the best way to go, I'll write some description about the solution (my understanding of the replacement policy, point out my assumptions about things that aren't mentioned .. etc) ... then I'll solve it, I think I can get probably 5 or 6 out of 10 for that.

Thank you very much sir for your help.